# How to extract string in file and replace specific pattern text

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I edit markdown file and insert the image. The content is like

```
1. This is some content
![](directory/regist.png)
2. This is some other content ![](directory/user_registered.png)
```

I want to parse the content into Hexo asset image format. The wanted content is like

```
1. This is some content
{% asset_img regist.png %}
2. This is some other content {% asset_img user_registered.png %}
```

I can use some programming code like java or python to read the file line by line and find the `![](` patthen and extract the file name and combine to new string like `{% asset_img regist.png %}`. But this seems not so smart.

I also search for `sed` and regualar express. I work on to `sed -i -E 's/!\[(.*?)\]((.*?)\/?(.*?))/\{% asset_img $3 %\}/g' test.md` right now. But it doesn't work, it generate new file `test.md-E` but nothing changed. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: With which langage are you trying to replace the string? BTW separately from the langage you use, your Regex should looks like something like `\!\[\]\((.*)\)`

Comment: @Bastien , Java or python both are ok. Right now I'm thinking if I can achieve this with one command instead of block of codes.

Comment: @Bastien, I don't see `!` needs to be escaped. By the way I add `\!`, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
sed -i.bak 's/!\[]([^()]*\/\([^)]*\))/{% asset_img \1 %}/g' file
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/GFpiPT/1)

Regex breakdown:

- `!\[]` Match `![]` literally
- `(` Match an opening parenthesis

  - `[^()]*\/` Match up to and including last slash mark
  - `\(` Start of capturing group 1

    - `[^)]*` Match up to next closing parenthesis
  - `\)` End of capturing group 1
- `)` Match a closing parenthesis

Comment: Thank you revo. Your command works. I need to chew your command little by little.

Comment: what if the text is like `![](directory(with)name/regist.png)`? `[^()]*\/` matches text to `/` with no `(` or `)`

Comment: I thought to `[^\/]*\/`, it can't match `![](directory(with)na/me/regist.png)` but meets my needs now.

Comment: Sed regex flavor has limited syntax. If you are able to use other flavors (as in other languages) you are in more chance for getting expected result from such input strings.